# Disable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 on Cherrypy, Python3

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl, cherrypy

I am trying to disable TLS1.0, TLS1.1, SSL2, and SSL3 on my cherrypy server.  I have seen the other stack over flow posts regarding how to disable them however, when I follow the code samples, I get the following error "ValueError: certfile must be specified for server-side operations".  The windows service is still running, however I cannot load any pages.  I've tried adding the certificate_chain as well, but that prevents cherrypy from running at all.

I am running cherrypy as a windows service, python 3.4.4, cherrypy 5.0.1, pyOpenSSL 19.0.0.

I've tried using the built in SSl library and with pyOpenSSL, they both result in the same error.

```py
import OpenSSL.SSL as ssl

context = ssl.Context(ssl.SSLv23_METHOD)
context.set_cipher_list('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384')
context.set_options(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3)
context.use_privatekey_file('myfile.key')
context.use_certificate_file('myfile.cer')

cherrypy.config.update({
    'global':{
        'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0',
        'server.socket_port': 0000, # https, however not using the port 443
        'server.ssl_context' : context,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Is myfile.cer in PEM format?  According to the docs it appears that PEM is the default filetype, which may be the cause of the error.

I'm also trying to figure out how to use ECDHE with Cherrypy, but with other web servers to use ECDHE there needs to be a curve file to generate the ephemeral key instead of a static key file (RSA style).  It doesn't appear that Cherrypy has built-in capabilities for the curve file so it may only be possible with pyOpenSSL.  The command to get the supported curves is `OpenSSL.crypto.get_elliptic_curves()` and you can specify the curve you want with `context.set_tmp_ecdh(curve)`.

Comment: I'm not super well versed with certificates but I found this "PEM data is commonly stored in files with a ".pem" suffix, a ".cer" or ".crt" suffix (for certificates), or a ".key" suffix (for public or private keys)."  Which led me to believe myfile.cer was acceptable? I'm not sure if the file has to be .pem or based on the quoted sentence above .cer is also valid

Comment: @chris If you open the file with a text editor does it looks something like this, [link] https://images.app.goo.gl/WVe6AiTfj6VuLN2w5?  That's a long shot since pyOpenSSL seems good about throwing errors on the cert import.  I think the issue might be due to 'server.ssl_context' being deprecated.  I can't find it in the documentation after cherrypy 3.3.  Also I had to use `context.set_cipher_list(b'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384')` to test your code.  It took your command, but threw a deprecation warning that a string was no longer accepted.

Comment: actually that is what my .cer file looks like when I open it. Sorry for the slow response, I ended up putting nginx in front of my cherrypy servers and disabled TLS1.0, TLS1.1, SSL2, and SSL3 there.

Comment: Thanks Josh White. Your comment on `server.ssl_context` being deprecated helped a lot. For reference the new configuration is `ssl_adapter.context`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there may be some issues in syntax: ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1  s/b ssl.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1 (per the pyOpenSSL documentation).  This affects all of the OP* variables.

Oh, wait... nvrmd that.